# why the first row of the sorting is all 0

Tags: c++

I want to make a Student achievement management system.
The other funtions are right. But the Sorting function always has a little problem. The first row is all 0. the sorting funtion will display the first line with all 0

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class student
{
    int num;
    char name[20];
    char class1[20];
    float Chinese;
    float math;
    float English;
    float aver;//平均成绩



public:
    void set()
    {

        cout << "\t学生学号:";
        cin >> num;
        cout << "\t学生姓名:";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "\t学生班级:";
        cin >> class1;
        cout << "\t语文成绩:";
        cin >> Chinese;
        cout << "\t英语成绩:";
        cin >> English;
        cout << "\t数学成绩:";
        cin >> math;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout << "该学生的学号：" << num << endl;
        cout << "该学生的姓名：" << name << endl;
        cout << "该学生的班级：" << class1 << endl;
        cout << "该学生的语文成绩：" << Chinese << endl;
        cout << "该学生的数学成绩：" << math << endl;
        cout << "该学生的英语成绩：" << English << endl;
    }

    friend  void    show();
    friend  void    search();
    friend  void    change();
    friend  void    add();
    friend  void    sort();
    friend  void    del();

};
void    input();
void    show();
void    search();
void    change();
void    add();
void    sort();
void    del();
student s[100];
int n = 0;

int main()
{

    int select;
    while (1)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\t ******************欢迎使用******************\n";
        cout << "\t **************学生成绩管理系统**************\n";
        cout << "\t *------------------------------------------*\n";
        cout << "\t *         1——录入学生信息                *\n";
        cout << "\t *         2——显示学生信息                *\n";
        cout << "\t *         3——查询学生信息                *\n";
        cout << "\t *         4——修改学生信息                *\n";
        cout << "\t *         5——添加学生信息                *\n";
        cout << "\t *         6——排序学生信息                *\n";
        cout << "\t *         7——删除学生信息                *\n";
        cout << "\t *         0——退出                        *\n";
        cout << "\t *------------------------------------------*\n";
        cout << "\t 你要输入的编号是（0--7）:";
        cin >> select;
        if (select == 0) break;
        switch (select) {
        case 1:
            input(); //调用input函数录入数据
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 2:
            show(); //调用show函数显示学生信息 
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 3:
            search();  //调用search函数查询学生信息
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 4:
            change();  //调用change函数修改学生信息
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 5:
            add();     //调用add函数添加学生信息
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 6:
            paixu();     //调用add函数添加学生信息
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 7:
            del();    // 调用del函数删除学生信息
            system("pause");
            break;



            system("pause");
        default:
            cout << "没有此选项,请重新选择！" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void input() //录入学生信息的函数
{
    char sel;
    do
    {
        n++;
        cout << "\t请输入第" << n << "个学生信息:\t" << endl;
        s[n].set();
        cout << "是否要继续录入学生信息(Y/N):";
        cin >> sel;
    } while (sel == 'Y' || sel == 'y');
}
void show()
{
    cout << left; //设置输出左对齐
    cout << setw(10) << "学生学号"
        << setw(10) << "学生姓名"
        << setw(13) << "学生班级"
        << setw(12) << "语文成绩"
        << setw(12) << "数学成绩"
        << setw(12) << "英语成绩"
        << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(10) << s[i].num
            << setw(10) << s[i].name
            << setw(13) << s[i].class1
            << setw(12) << s[i].Chinese
            << setw(12) << s[i].math
            << setw(12) << s[i].English << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

}

void search()//查询
{

    int a, b, i; char c[20];
    cout << "请选择查询方式：" << endl;
    cout << "按学生姓名查询请按1" << endl;
    cout << "按学生学号查询请按2" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
    {char sel;
    do {
        cout << "请输入你要查的学生的姓名：" << endl;
        cin >> c;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            if (strcmp(s[i].name, c) == 0)
            {
                cout << "你要查的学生信息为：" << endl;
                cout << "学生学号：" << s[i].num << endl << "学生姓名："
                    << s[i].name << endl << "学生班级："
                    << s[i].class1 << endl << "语文成绩："
                    << s[i].Chinese << endl << "数学成绩："
                    << s[i].math << endl << "英语成绩："
                    << s[i].English << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp(s[i].name, c) != 0 && i == n)
            {
                cout << "没有这个学生！" << endl; break;
            }
        cout << "是否要继续查询学生信息(Y/N):";
        cin >> sel;
    } while (sel == 'Y' || sel == 'y');
    break;
    }
    case 2:
    {   char sel;
    do {
        cout << "请输入你要查的学生的学号：" << endl;
        cin >> b;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            if (s[i].num == b)
            {
                cout << "你要查的学生信息为：" << endl;
                cout << "学生学号：" << s[i].num << endl << "学生姓名："
                    << s[i].name << endl << "学生班级："
                    << s[i].class1 << endl << "语文成绩："
                    << s[i].Chinese << endl << "数学成绩："
                    << s[i].math << endl << "英语成绩："
                    << s[i].English << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (s[i].num != b&&i == n)
            {
                cout << "没有这个学生！请核对后再输入！" << endl; break;
            }
        cout << "是否要继续查询学生信息(Y/N):";
        cin >> sel;
    } while (sel == 'Y' || sel == 'y');
    break; }

    default:
        cout << "您的输入有误!" << endl;
    }

}

void change()
{
    {   char sel;
    int d, i, e, f, g = 0;
    do {
        cout << "请输入你要修改的学生的学号：" << endl;
        cin >> d;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            if (s[i].num == d)
            {
                cout << "你要修改的学生信息为：" << endl;
                cout << "学生学号：" << s[i].num << endl << "学生姓名："
                    << s[i].name << endl << "学生班级："
                    << s[i].class1 << endl << "语文成绩："
                    << s[i].Chinese << endl << "数学成绩："
                    << s[i].math << endl << "英语成绩："
                    << s[i].English << endl;
                e = 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (s[i].num != d&&i == n)
            {
                cout << "没有这个学生！请核对后再输入！" << endl;
                e = 0; break;
            }
        while (e == 1)
        {
            {cout << "请输入该学生要修改的信息对应的数字：" << endl;
            cout << "学生学号：1"
                << '\t' << "学生姓名：2"
                << '\t' << "学生班级：3"
                << '\t' << "语文成绩：4"
                << '\t' << "数学成绩：5"
                << '\t' << "英语成绩：6" << endl;
            }
            cin >> f;
            switch (f)
            {
            case 1:cout << "\t新的学生学号为:";
                cin >> s[i].num; break;
            case 2:cout << "\t新的学生姓名为:";
                cin >> s[i].name; break;
            case 3:cout << "\t新的学生班级为:";
                cin >> s[i].class1; break;
            case 4:cout << "\t新的语文成绩为:";
                cin >> s[i].Chinese; break;
            case 5:cout << "\t新的数学成绩为:";
                cin >> s[i].math; break;
            case 6:cout << "\t新的英语成绩为:";
                cin >> s[i].English; break;
            default:cout << "您的输入有误，请重新输入！";
                cin >> f;
            }
            e = 0;
            g = 1;
        }
        if (g == 1)
        {
            cout << "修改成功！";
        }
        cout << "是否要继续修改学生信息(Y/N):";
        cin >> sel;
    } while (sel == 'Y' || sel == 'y');
    }

}

void add()
{
    char sel;
    do
    {
        n++;
        cout << "\n请输入第" << n << "个学生信息:\n";
        cout << "\t学生学号:";
        cin >> s[n].num;
        cout << "\t学生姓名:";
        cin >> s[n].name;
        cout << "\t学生班级:";
        cin >> s[n].class1;
        cout << "\t语文成绩:";
        cin >> s[n].Chinese;
        cout << "\t数学成绩:";
        cin >> s[n].math;
        cout << "\t英语成绩:";
        cin >> s[n].English;
        cout << "是否要继续添加学生信息(Y/N):";
        cin >> sel;
    } while (sel == 'Y' || sel == 'y');

}


void sort()
{
    student w;

    for (int i = 0; i<n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<n - 1-i; j++)
            if (s[j].aver < s[j + 1].aver)
            {
                w = s[j]; s[j] = s[j + 1]; s[j + 1] = w;
            }
    cout << "按平均成绩排序结果：" << endl;
    cout << left; //设置输出左对齐
    cout << setw(10) << "学生学号"
        << setw(10) << "学生姓名"
        << setw(13) << "学生班级"
        << setw(12) << "语文成绩"
        << setw(12) << "数学成绩"
        << setw(12) << "英语成绩"
        << setw(12) << "平均成绩"
        << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k <n ; k++)
    {
        s[k].aver = (s[k].math + s[k].Chinese + s[k].English) / 3;
        cout << setw(10) << s[k].num
            << setw(10) << s[k].name
            << setw(13) << s[k].class1
            << setw(12) << s[k].Chinese
            << setw(12) << s[k].math
            << setw(12) << s[k].English
            << setw(12) << s[k].aver << endl;
    }

}
void del()
{

    int j, i, k; char c[10], sel, y;
    do {
        cout << "请输入你要删除的学生的姓名：" << endl;
        cin >> c;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            if (strcmp(s[i].name, c) == 0)
            {
                cout << "你要删除的学生信息为：" << endl;
                cout << "学生学号：" << s[i].num << endl
                    << "学生姓名：" << s[i].name << endl
                    << "学生班级：" << s[i].class1 << endl
                    << "语文成绩：" << s[i].Chinese << endl
                    << "数学成绩：" << s[i].math << endl
                    << "英语成绩：" << s[i].English << endl;
                cout << "确认删除？（y/n）:";
                cin >> y;
                if (y == 'Y' || y == 'y')
                {
                    for (j = i; j <= n + 1; j++)
                    {
                        s[j] = s[j + 1];
                    }   k = 1;
                }
                else
                    cout << "删除失败！" << endl;


                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp(s[i].name, c) != 0 && i == n)
            {
                cout << "没有这个学生！请核对后再输入！" << endl;
                k = 0; break;
            }
        while (k == 1)
        {
            if (y == 'Y' || y == 'y')
                cout << "删除成功！";
            n--;
            k = 0;
        }
        cout << "是否要继续删除学生信息(Y/N):";
        cin >> sel;

    } while (sel == 'Y' || sel == 'y');

}
```

Comment: Please I don't think this is important here but when you post question could you trad the **comment** in English ?

Comment: ^ I think it's okay. I understood the code just fine. The strings don't really matter. @JeffYoung what do you mean by the first row is all 0? Could you edit your post and add the output you're currently getting?

Comment: There are 400 lines of code here. Please reduce this to a [mcve] by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Could you narrow this down to just the problem you are having?  There's a lot of code that's very likely unnecessary to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I feel sorry，I did it in a hurry

Comment: I won't read such long code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `add` function, you increment `n` before using it as an index into your `s` array.  This leaves `s[0]` empty (so you have a row of all zeros), and `s[n]` with the last entry (so it won't be included in the sort).

Store all your inputs in `add`, *then* increment `n`.